# How can I prevent unnecessary recompiling of Protobuf-generated files with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have GRPC in a sub-directory,  so I have the Protobuf target name and the GRPC C++ plugin target name. How could I generate the proto files without the need to recompile every time either CMake or Build targets wants to run?

The current setting:

```
add_custom_target(ThatThing
  COMMAND 
    $<TARGET_FILE:${proto_target}>
      --grpc_out=generate_mock_code=true:${the_output_dir}
      --cpp_out=${the_output_dir}
      --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$<TARGET_FILE:${grpc_cpp_plugin_target}>
      -I ${that_dir}
      ${those_proto_files}
)
add_dependencies(${that_dependent_target_name} ThatThing)
```

But here we have a rebuild on the generated files every time that we want to build. One way is to only generate those files in CMake's generate-time by checking if those files are generated. But the `execute_process` function seems to can't understand neither the `$<TARGET_FILE>` genexpr nor the target name:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${protoc_path} --help COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)
```

will fail with:

```bash
execute_process error getting child return code: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why, but I can't get the `LOCATION` property of the target:

```
get_target_property(the_location ${protoc_path} LOCATION)
```

will fail with:

```bash
  The LOCATION property may not be read from target "protoc".  Use the target
  name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator expression
  $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
```

And also `find_program` function can't use `$<TARGET_FILE>` genexpr:

```
find_program(that_location ${protoc_path} REQUIRED)
find_program(that_location $<TARGET_FILE:${protoc_path}> REQUIRED)
```

How could I fix the unnecessary recompilation problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) is that *the target is always considered out of date*.
If you use [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#command:add_custom_command) instead,  it will only be rebuild when the files specified in `DEPENDS` changed.

This is better than a config time solution, as it will regenerate the target during a build if any of the input files changed.

Note that if you need the generated files for multiple targets, you should add a dummy target for them, as [demonstrated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#example-generating-files-for-multiple-targets) in the documentation for `add_custom_command`.